# mySQL - query to get floor() or round() to next lowest 100 unit (hundred block number for address)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a query to take integer street address numbers and get the hundred block number for the address.  E.g. any value from 300 to 399 yields 300 etc.

Is this possible in a single query or should I write a script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT number - MOD( number, 100 )
```

Comment: Clever solution!

Answer (score 11):

you can use floor like this :

```
SELECT FLOOR(399/100)*100;
```